# WCF bindings at service side

Tags: wcf

How can we define bindings with Max buffer size at WCF service side rather than doing at client side. Can somebody let me know if this is feasible? I do not want to customize bindings at client side.

Comment: Create an appropriate config file on your server. If you're hosting your WCF service inside IIS, you need a  `web.config` and if you're self-hosting the WCF service, you need an `app.config` for the host application.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you! Add **maxRequestLength=214748364** in *Web.Config*.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="300"/>    
</system.web>
```

And if it doesn't work Add this in  tag.

```
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webHttpBG" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
              <security mode="None"/>
          </binding>

      </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

And in your  tag. Do something like this.

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="" name="Your.Service.Name">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="webHttpBG" contract="Your.Package.IContract" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:51855/Contract.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Comment: Would I get below bindings at client side ?
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webHttpBG" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
              <security mode="None"/>
          </binding>

      </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

Comment: No, these all are Server side! Make changes in your Web.Config file of your WCF project.